# Populate sequence by group in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Populate sequence by group in sql server:

Input:-

```
ID  data
1    0
1    0
1    0
2    0
2    0
2    0
```

Output:-

```
ID  data
1    0
1    1
1    2
2    0
2    1
2    2
```

Comment: You need to add context and additional information on what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried so far, and where you're encountering an issue. As it stands your post is very hard to interpret.

Comment: There is no semantic difference in your input between different rows. What you want can be obtained with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ???)`, but you have no column for the `???` to actually order the rows.

Comment: Please add in question body details of logic to generate expected output.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, per your sample data, you need to use `ROW_NUMBER()` along with partitioning.

```
SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) as DATA
FROM <table>
```

But because the `ID` column is not unique, the `ORDER BY` will not know how to discern between the first row with `1` and the third row with `1`.

Which is why, I recommend in the `ORDER BY ID` part, to also add a unique/primary key column which will give you a deterministic order, so that you can always determine what value a certain row will have, in a fixed set of data.

So, if your table also contains a "PK" (primary key) **or unique** column:

```
PK    ID     data
1     1      0
2     1      1
3     1      2
4     2      0
5     2      1
6     2      2
```

then your select can turn into:

```
SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, PK) as DATA
FROM <table>
```

Comment: Note that this produces a non-deterministic order since all the `ID`s are necessarily the same, which is fine for the table as literally posted in the question, but can give insidiously surprising results if there are actually more columns involved. (Insidious as in, they may appear to be what you want, when in fact tomorrow they might change.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I totally agree with it and thought about adding more information, but since this is the limited scenario OP posted, I went with a minimalist answer. For the amount of effort put into asking and giving details about the question, I think giving him a partial answer (that can later cause another question to come up - the scenario you mentioned) is in my view a lesson in the right direction. Might not be fair though, *haven't decided on that part*...

Comment: Since questions and answers are potentially read by more than just the OP, I thought putting in a comment to protect innocent future readers wouldn't go amiss. (Admittedly since this has now been downvoted and closed there probably aren't going to be that many future readers, but it's the principle of the thing.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you for making me lean into the right direction. I've added more details to the answer, for future readers.